# Linux scipt variable is not recognized properly

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have a question about shell scripting in Linux.
I've been trying to get this code working for hours now, and it does something I don't understand. The purpose of the code would be to add users with the values for the name, gecos and group in a csv file.
the csv file is formatted as followed:

```
U12341;Mario Speedwagon;docent
U12342;Petey Cruiser;classA
```

This is my code, I removed the group function in useradd temporary as it was easier to debug that way. It kept telling me that ` was an invalid name for the group. So I tried putting the variables on screen with an echo and noticed something very strange to me.

```
for actie in `more +2 users.csv | tr " " "_"`
do
login=`echo $actie | tr ";" ":" | cut --delimiter=: --field=1 | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-$
groep=`echo $actie | tr ";" ":" | cut --delimiter=: --field=3`;
gecos=`echo $actie | tr ";" ":" | cut --delimiter=: --field=2 | tr "_" " "`;

echo "In login ($login), in gecos ($gecos) en in groep ($groep)"
sudo useradd $login -c "$gecos"
echo "User $login is toegevoegd onder de naam $gecos in groep $groep"

done
```

This was the strange output:

```
)n login (u12341), in gecos (Mario Speedwagon) en in groep (docent
useradd: user 'u12341' already exists
User u12341 is toegevoegd onder de naam Mario Speedwagon in groep docent
)n login (u12342), in gecos (Petey Cruiser) en in groep (classA
useradd: user 'u12342' already exists
```

It seems to put the character after the $group over the first character of the string. I think my problem using that same variable as a group name is exactly the same.

Everything else seems to work just fine, if I run the script without the group code, it adds users with the correct gecos data.

Has somebody experienced an issue like this before?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was the csv file made on a Windows machine? Windows ends lines with carriage-return + newline (`\r\n`), whereas Linux uses just a newline (`\n`). My guess is it's including the carriage return `\r` from the end of each line in your `groep` variable. Then when it echoes that variable, the `\r` without `\n` sends the cursor to the beginning of the line without moving to the next. (To demonstrate, try `echo -e "Here's a line of text to print with a \rcarriage return in the middle."`)

I don't know off-hand an automatic way to strip out the CRs (I'll see if I can find one), but you can run the file through sed or something and remove all occurrences of `\r`.

Edit:
Option 1: install `dos2unix` (the standard)
Option 2: `tr -d '\r' < input.file  > new.file` (lifted this from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/dos2unix-command-not-found-820134/#post4042798))
Option 3: Apparently just running `cat oldfile.csv > newfile.csv` will strip out the carriage returns. I don't have a file to test it on, but you could give it a try.

Comment: I tried your example of \r, that seems to be the problem indeed. I'll see if I can find a way to delete it (because it's not displayed in the text editor).

Edit: I tried copying the file like you said but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Either way I don't think I'm allowed to change the csv file.

Comment: You could use `tr -d '\r'` at the end of the pipes that get the `groep` variable.

Comment: Oh, didn't it? You learned something, right? I assume that was part of the lesson.

Comment: Haha :) yeah, I'd see him doing that. Thanks alot for your efforts!